# How to get dynamic text value in alpine js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, alpine.js

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<p @click="printThisTextToSpan">Name one</p>
<p @click="printThisTextToSpan">Name two</p>
<p @click="printThisTextToSpan">Name three</p>


<span ></span>
```

My Question is how can i print p tag text to span when i click on p tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having taken a glance at the [documentation](https://alpinejs.dev/start-here), I got this

```html
<script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ text: '' }">
    <p @click="text = $el.textContent">Name one</p>
    <p @click="text = $el.textContent">Name two</p>
    <p @click="text = $el.textContent">Name three</p>
 
    <span x-text="text"></span>
</div>
```

To use a function you need more code

https://codewithhugo.com/alpinejs-magic-property-access/

Comment: Where does it say $el.textContent is valid? It only says $el.innerHTML

Comment: @BobtheBuilder it’s the current DOM node so unless Alpine is stupid and limits access, then all DOM methods are available including textConten

Comment: Thansk can you see this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72076957/class-not-adding-class